# Quiero definir mi propia barra de tareas en tinyMCE y no consigo que incluya la totalidad de las funciones

Tags: toolbar, tinymce

He probado con esto:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  plugins: "nonbreaking",
  nonbreaking_force_tab: true,
  plugins: "charmap",
  plugins: 'codesample',
  codesample_global_prismjs: true,
  codesample_languages: [
    { text: 'HTML/XML', value: 'markup' },
    { text: 'JavaScript', value: 'javascript' },
    { text: 'CSS', value: 'css' },
    { text: 'PHP', value: 'php' },
    { text: 'Ruby', value: 'ruby' },
    { text: 'Python', value: 'python' },
    { text: 'Java', value: 'java' },
    { text: 'C', value: 'c' },
    { text: 'C#', value: 'csharp' },
    { text: 'C++', value: 'cpp' }
  ],
  toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | casechange bullist numlist outdent indent | forecolor backcolor | link image | print preview media fullpage | charmap | codesample | nonbreaking',

});
```

Pero no funciona en su totalidad. Muestra los íconos de las tareas mas comunes, pero sólo una de las funciones especiales (p. ej. codesample)

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/), la forma de declarar los plugins a incluir es:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  plugins : 'codesample charmap'
});
```

Los plugins van separados por espacio, en un solo elemento del array. En tu configuración actual, sólo toma el último elemento `plugins` que lee.